# Object doesn't support this property or method - jquery.min.js

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm developing a website and am testing in IE 8 and am getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" for ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

This error comes on only when I am at the home page, then I click one of the rectangular icons on the right, such as Lawn Care. I is supposed to highlight the word and scroll to it. It is fine if I'm already on the home page.

The site works in all browsers except IE 8. Please go to http://diginnovations.com/serenity to view it. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of your JavaScript and HTML in an easy to follow format. e.g. Recreate the problem with a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't see any issues with the site and I am using IE8

Comment: If you go to the maintenance link directly and click on one of the rectangle boxes on the right, then the left column will highlight orange and scroll to the correct area. So for instance, if you click on the Maintenance link, then click on Lawn Care, you should see it highlighted. But if you're on the home page and you click on Lawn Care, it will go to the Maintenance page, then scroll to lawn care, but will not highlight. And that's when you get the object error through IE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the JavaScript that is being executed when you load the page in an IE browser with a version greater than 6:

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li").removeClass("customTarget");
    var myLocation = document.location.hash.replace("#","");
    if (myLocation) {
        document.getElementById(myLocation).className = "customTarget";
    }

    $("a").click(function () {
        $("li").removeClass("customTarget");
        var clickedLink = this.href.split("#");
        if (clickedLink.length > 1) {
            document.getElementById(clickedLink[1]).className = "customTarget";
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

One of your problems is that you are not loading jQuery before this block of JavaScript. Therefore, `$` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the 1.4.4 declaration to the 'if IE 6' statement and it resolved it, but now it breaks the jscrollpane. When I add the jscrollpane js files into the 'if IE6' then it breaks it again.

Comment: Now you have moved all of your scripts, except for the IE one, to the HEAD of the document and are loading jQuery twice in IE. You only need to load the library once, and you need to load it before code that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem (that same error message and only in IE8) and these two lines I had were the culprit:

```
 menu = document.getElementById('limit' + i);
 menu.style.display = "block";
```

I fixed the error by replacing those two lines with:

```
 document.getElementById('limit' + i).style.display = "block";
```